# How to Recombine Responses that are Spread out in Different Columns

Tags: excel

[image]

Above is a simple representation of my spreadsheet. My survey data was exported in this messy format, with different categories of each question in a different column, even though there was only one response per question. I want to combine them so that all the "Satisfaction" responses are in one column, and same for "Sex".

There must be an easy way to do this? I tried looking it up but I'm not sure how to describe this format in my searches.

Help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to concatenate all of the columns into one column. If all of the rows have only one value this should work.

`=(A1 & "" & B1 & "" & C1)` from this you can just auto fill it down the sheet. After that you would want to copy the data from the new concatenated column and paste it as the literal values, so you don't lose the data when you erase the other columns.